# URL Classification in Python: How to know whether given URL belongs to homepage of blog or any article

Tags: python, algorithm, url, python-2.7, document-classification

I'm running a URL classifier algorithm. I have few URLs related to blogs and I want to find out whether entered URL is for any blogpost or URL for blog whle blog.

example 1 - if we enter following URL

```
http://gizmodo.com/
```

it will tell that above URL is homepage

example 2 - if we enter following URL

```
http://gizmodo.com/everyone-can-get-the-new-google-maps-right-now-805487210
```

it will tell that above URL is blogpost.

Is there anyway I can do that in Python? Is there any algorithm that I might be missing? Or any open source package or service?

Comment: Hmmm, you have two choices: preconfigured (hard-coded) rules or artificial intelligence (and similar adaptive solutions?). On what basis you tell homepages from blogs?

Comment: We have collection of blog URLs. They were collected by running crawler across some set of blogs that we added manually.

Comment: But going forward we want to add blog URLs automatically hence we are facing this issue

Comment: Let me reformulate my question: On what basis you distinguish "homepage" from "blogpost"? Assuming that `http://example.com/pages/tadeck` is homepage, while `http://example.org/notes/who-is-tadeck` can be a blogpost. What are the characteristics of a page showing "homepage" and page showing "blog post"?

Comment: Or maybe it is about distinguishing upper-level pages (homepages) from lower-level pages (eg. blog posts) within **same domain**?

Comment: "Or maybe it is about distinguishing upper-level pages (homepages) from lower-level pages (eg. blog posts) within same domain?" That's what I meant :) Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1):

The solution may be this, although it does not use any library:

```py
scraped_urls = [
    'http://gizmodo.com/everyone-can-get-the-new-google-maps-right-now-805487210',
    'http://gizmodo.com/no-one-can-get-new-ios-7-yet-8432234432',
    'http://gizmodo.com/world-war-z-on-google-play-for-free-2332343',
    'http://gizmodo.com/',
]

homepage = min(scraped_urls, key=len)
blogposts = [url for url in scraped_urls if url != homepage]
```

See demonstration here: http://ideone.com/z9CHO9

The code assumes that you have a set (technically a `list`, not a `set` here, but both are okay) of URLs scraped from single server, and that the homepage URL is the shortest (which should be true, as far as website has some consistent naming and you can extract structure from the URL).

Answer (score 0):

Use the urlparse module and check the .path attribute

```
    import urlparse
    result = urlparse.urlsplit(myURL)
    print result.path
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a scalable approach. What if blog url is myurl.com/blog or myurl.com/technology/blog?